# How much data / file which is in PDF format I can store in One List in Office 365 small

Tags: list, document-library, office-365

I'm using Office 365 Small. I want to know in one List/Library in GB how much data/file I can store. I know I can store 5000 items in one List but here I'm have to store PDF files in document Library / List so want to know how much data / file which is in PDF format I can store in One List in Office 365 small.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer so posting here if any one looking for the same.In one List we can upload max 5000 items if it will go more than that so it will generate error.

And we can upload the files (in any format) up to 1 TB in one Site collection when site collection is empty.